# There was a problem with reindexing process

Tags: php, mysql

When I try to reindex the product attributes, as you may expect, it gives me the following error "There was a problem with reindexing process."

On the **Mage_Index_Adminhtml_ProcessController**, line 133, I was able to retrieve the error (via $e->getMessage()), but now I don't realy know how to fix it.

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`catalog_product_index_eav`, CONSTRAINT `FK_CAT_PRD_IDX_EAV_ENTT_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`entity_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_product_entity` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE C)
```

Can you please point me on the right direction ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the lock files in `var/locks` and try again.

I'd advise you reindex in SSH if you have a large data set

```
php shell/indexer.php -reindexall
```